# How to turn a function into an async function inside of a functions folder

Tags: javascript, discord.js

so im trying to have the bot run a command that checks the roles of everyone in the database every hour or so. pretty sure i need it to be async for the database portion of this if i remember correctly. i cant figure out how to properly word this to get it to work.

i know how to make an async function normally but im making a functions folder to keep my code clean and from there i dont know how to turn one into a function because normal syntax does not work. most things i find when i google/look here is stuff for inside the code or inside the message handler not for inside a functions folder.

the question being. how can i properly word this to become an async function?

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
let connection;
module.exports = {
    // we need to declare the name first, then add the function
    autoRoleCheck: function (message) { 
        // find id of user who sent message
        let userId = await message.member.id;
        //find owner of the guild the message was sent in
        let owner = message.guild.ownerID        
        // Guild the user needs to have the role in
        let myGuild = bot.guilds.fetch(process.env.BOT_GUILD);
        console.log(myGuild);
    }
    // here we can add more functions, divided by a comma
}

// if you want to export only one function
// declare it normally and then export it
module.exports = autoRoleCheck;
```

Comment: `autoRoleCheck: async function`

Answer (score 0):

Just add the `async` keyword in front of your function to make it asynchronous. You should then be able to use await syntax.

```js
autoRoleCheck: async function(message) {
```

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
let connection;
module.exports = {
  // we need to declare the name first, then add the function
  autoRoleCheck: async function(message) { // <-- change made here
    // find id of user who sent message
    let userId = await message.member.id;
    //find owner of the guild the message was sent in
    let owner = message.guild.ownerID
    // Guild the user needs to have the role in
    let myGuild = await bot.guilds.fetch(process.env.BOT_GUILD);
    console.log(myGuild);
  }
  // here we can add more functions, divided by a comma
}

// if you want to export only one function
// declare it normally and then export it
module.exports = autoRoleCheck;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have the function wrapped in the module.exports, and then export it again later.

Try defining the function first, and then exporting it. Something more like

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
require('dotenv').config();
const mysql = require('mysql2');
let connection;

// we need to declare the name first, then add the function
async function autoRoleCheck(message) { 
    // find id of user who sent message
    let userId = await message.member.id;
    //find owner of the guild the message was sent in
    let owner = await message.guild.ownerID        
    // Guild the user needs to have the role in
    let myGuild = await bot.guilds.fetch(process.env.BOT_GUILD);
    console.log(myGuild);
}
    


// if you want to export only one function
// declare it normally and then export it
module.exports = { autoRoleCheck };
```

I've added the awaits to everything within the function, because I have no idea what's actually accessing the database here. You actually shouldn't need to await anything with the message, because you are passing it in to the function when you call it. (Unless you're passing a promise along, at which point, those awaits will be handy).

Answer (score 0):

The best way to define a function in an object is by using this syntax:

```js
let someObj = {
someFunction(arg1, arg2) {
//code
},
async someAsyncFn(arg1, arg2) {
//async code
}
}
```

The execution is super easy to do:

```js
someObj.someFunction(arg1, arg2)
someObj.someAsyncFunction(arg1, arg2)
```

Comment: Why is this the best way?

Comment: It uses the least amount of space, and is well-readable